# Disable selection based on previous Dropdown menu selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, selection

Ran into a problem that is causing some snags. I am making a product configurator for my company. Essentially, all of our products are custom, so different components may not be compatible with other components.

What I am trying to do is disable selections on different dropdown menus based on previous dropdown menu selections.

i.e1. If I choose Universal in my "Controller Type" section, in my "Series Type" section, I want all of the options grayed out.

i.e2. If I choose EAFV Base Mount (Horizontal) in my "Controller Type" section, in my "Series Type" section, I want all of the options available.

i.e3. If I choose EAFV Base Mount (Vertical) in my "Controller Type" section, in my "Series Type" section, I want all of the options available except for 4:1 and 6:1.

I would like to do this with Javascript/Jquery if possible. I have looked on Stackoverflow and various Google search results for the answer and they do not offer the help I need. I appreciate any and all help with this and can provide any additional information needed.

Thank you!

Comment: There are some dedicated plugins. I.e: [dependent-dropdown](https://github.com/kartik-v/dependent-dropdown) or [jquery-dependent-selects](https://github.com/simpleweb/jquery-dependent-selects) . I believe that there's more of them, just need to google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about first defining your rules:

```
var controllerTypeFunctions = {
    Default:function(){
        $('#series option').prop('disabled',false);   
    },
    UV: function(){
        $('#series option').prop('disabled',true);   
    },
    EAFVH: function(){
        $('#series option').prop('disabled',false);   
    },
    EAFVV: function(){
        $('#series option').filter(function(){
           return this.value == "4" || this.value == "6"
        }).prop('disabled',true);   
    }    
}
```

And then calling the right rule based on the value:

```
$('#type').on('change',function(){
    controllerTypeFunctions.Default(); //resets all to enabled

    var val = $(this).val();
    controllerTypeFunctions[val]();
});
```

Live example below:

```js
var controllerTypeFunctions = {
    Default:function(){
        $('#series option').prop('disabled',false);   
    },
    UV: function(){
        $('#series option').prop('disabled',true);   
    },
    EAFVH: function(){
        $('#series option').prop('disabled',false);   
    },
    EAFVV: function(){
        $('#series option').filter(function(){
           return this.value == "4" || this.value == "6"
        }).prop('disabled',true);   
    }    
}


$('#type').on('change',function(){
    controllerTypeFunctions.Default();
    
    var val = $(this).val();
    controllerTypeFunctions[val]();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b>Controller Type</b><br>
    <select id="type">
    <option value="">Select One</option>
    <option value="CR">Rack Mount</option>
    <option value="CS">Portable</option>
    <option value="EAFVV">EAFV Base Mount (Vertical 62 Series)</option>
    <option value="EAFVH">EAFV Base Mount (Horizontal Base)</option>
    <option value="CC">Chassis Box (Hoffman Enclosure)</option>
    <option value="PAFV">PAFV Base Mount</option>
    <option value="UV">Universal</option>
    <option value="HO">High Output Single Channel</option>
    <option value="LO">Low Output Single Channel</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
     <b>Series Type</b><br>
     <p class="series"><font size="1">Only applies to certain controller  types</font></p>
    <select id="series" onchange="updateText('series')">
     <option value="">Select One</option>
     <option value="1" data-temp="EAFVV">1:1</option>
     <option value="2">2:1</option>
     <option value="4">4:1</option>
     <option value="6">6:1</option>
</select>
<br>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code, it works perfect in the "Run Code Snippet". However, I am still unable to get this to work on my website. I am so sorry if I am making stupid mistakes, I have only been working with code for a couple weeks. Currently, I have this as my code in JSFiddle copying my HTML and your Javascript/JQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/ro2dv5k1/5/ . The Javascript/JQuery script is called out in my HTML and is located at: http://www.flexotherm.net/templates/yoo_corona/js/tso.js . It doesnt work on JSFiddle and I dont see any console errors on my screen.

Comment: @FlexMarket You have the same error message in that fiddle that I pointed out before *ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side*
`if (parseInt($(this).attr('data-temp')) = type) {`

Comment: I FINALLY found where you were seeing that error. Seems I forgot to scrap an old Javascript/Jquery script that was still calling out those variables. So sorry about my mistakes! The code is finally working on my website with no problems! Many thanks!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but would I use that same Javascript/Jquery code to affect other selections? Like could I choose "Universal" which would gray out the entire "Series Type" section and then have 240V and 480V under "Voltage" be grayed out as well, based on the "Universal" selection? As always, my code is here if you have time to look at it: http://jsfiddle.net/m31kcf54/

Comment: @FlexMarket - you can do whatever you like inside each function. See [this update](http://jsfiddle.net/m31kcf54/1/) - I commented out one line and added one line, then copied the code you already had for the voltage below into that function. You could start writing functions that can be called instead of copy/pasting code, i'll leave that as an exercise for you ;)

Comment: Thanks for that! I ran into a small problem though. If I switch the Controller Type, the other dropdown menu items stay grayed out when it should be available for other types. It can be recreated by doing the following: Pick Rack Mount from the Controller Type dropdown, choose 8 in the Channels dropdown, Pick Portable from the Controller Type, Choose 1 in the Channels dropdown, Pick EAFV Vertical from the dropdown, try to choose 4 in the Channels dropdown. All selections will be grayed out when 4 should be available.

Comment: My current HTML is at http://jsfiddle.net/qr073rmx/ and my Jquery is at http://www.flexotherm.net/templates/yoo_corona/js/tso.js if you have time to check it out. I Google'd this problem and the only results were just resetting the dropdown menu selection.

Comment: @FlexMarket - Am I getting your salary too?

Comment: Web design is not my job at my company. My boss wanted me to try and tackle this project and I have received some good responses from Stackoverflow in the past. I thought it may be a simple fix. Sorry to bother you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
$("#type").change(function () {
    var selectList = document.getElementById("type");
    if (selectList.value === "UV") {
        $("#series option").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    } else if (selectList.value === "EAFVH") {
        $("#series option").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else if (selectList.value === "EAFVV") {
        $("#series option").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#series option:nth-child(4)").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#series option:nth-child(5)").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    } else {
        $("#series option").removeAttr("disabled");
    } 
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! However, I modified my onchange attribute of the Controller Type and it is not working still unfortunately. The modified code (Only the top to the end of Controller Type) is located here: http://jsfiddle.net/ro2dv5k1/ . The Javascript/Jquery code you gave me that is being loaded is located at: http://www.flexotherm.net/templates/yoo_corona/js/tempsensoroptions.js . If you have some time, could you see if I did anything wrong?

Comment: I have modified the code to not need the onchange attribute. All you should need to do now is paste it in, and if there haven't been any changes to your HTML since posting this should work. Try the edited version and tell me how it goes. You shouldn't need the document ready bit with this either.

Comment: the enabled/disabled state of an input element should be handled using [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) not `attr`. *"Properties generally affect the dynamic state of a DOM element without changing the serialized HTML attribute. Examples include the value property of input elements, the disabled property of inputs and buttons, or the checked property of a checkbox. The .prop() method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr() method. "*

Comment: @AshtonFrench I appreciate all the help with this. Unfortunately, it is still not functioning. I took the updated code to JSFiddle and it isnt working as well. Here is the page: http://jsfiddle.net/ro2dv5k1/2/ . I tried it with and without the document ready code to no avail.

Comment: @FlexMarket - you have a javascript error in that fiddle (use of `=` for evaluation instead of `==`), watch the console!

Comment: @FlexMarket I went to the fiddle and saw that the console was throwing out plenty of 'not defined' type errors, so I stripped it down to just the functionality talked about in this question and it seems to work as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/ro2dv5k1/4/
Check your tempchoicetoseries.js file and then also make sure you are testing it without triggering undefined functions like 'updateText'

Comment: @Jamiec Thanks for the input, I wasn't aware of the differences between the two but will be sure to use this going forward.

Comment: @AshtonFrench I finally have it working on my website. Thank you so much for the help!